# How could I optimize MyMaximum- LikeliHood function in R

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, stochastic, log-likelihood

estimator in R. Therefore i need to get the maximum out of a Maximum Likelihood function. My score function is

```
LL <- function(theta){
  b0 <- theta[1]
  b1 <- theta[2]
  b2 <- theta[3]
  b3 <- theta[4]
  SigmaV <- theta[5]
  Gamma <- theta[6]
  res <- Y - b0 - b1 * X1 - b2 * X2 - b3*X3
  score <- 0
  for(i in 1:x){
    score <- score + log((2/(sqrt(SigmaV^2+Gamma^2))) * dnorm(res[i]/sqrt(SigmaV^2+Gamma^2))*pnorm((-res[i]/sqrt(SigmaV^2+Gamma^2))*(Gamma/SigmaV)))
  }
  score
}
```

So its an Optimization for an SFA Modell.

I tried many options (optim, mle2 and some others). One of the best was to use optim:

```
FitfürNormalenFall <- optim(c(1,1,1,1,0.2,0.3), LL, 
                          method = "BFGS",
                           control=list(fnscale=-1))
```

But the Starting Values are random. I just choose the values. The real values are

```
a0 <- 0.9
a1 <- 0.6
a2 <- 0.5
a3 <- 1
sigmaV <- 0.25
gamma <- 0.3
```

But i dont get somewhere near the Values with this kind of algorithm. Which would be an optimization Method I could use or what are good starting values and other instructions for optim so i get near the real values?

Comment: The input data is missing from the question.

Comment: If I use the LM Values, i get a non finite function value